# Major Questions resolved or unresolved in Philosophy

Tags: history-of-philosophy

Is there any collection of the major Questions that have driven philosophical thought through the ages? I'm not strictly referring to the branches of philosophy but the arguments therein. Thanks

Comment: You have to understand very clearly as you see yourself in the mirror. Do you see yourself now? Great people who created philosophy were interested in **everything**. But mainly they liked to think and feel. There are several doors(problems) to philosophy - Death, Existence, Sufferings, Knowledge, Power/Free will. Every philosopher entered one or many or all of these doors in his findings.

Comment: Are you looking for a reference, or are you asking for that list? Because the first would be a reference request (and could be tagged accordingly), the other would probably be too broad to answer...

Comment: @iphigenie i'd be interested in the latter like the one referenced by joseph weissman below

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wikipedia has a list of [unsolved problems in philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unsolved_problems_in_philosophy); this is drawn from the outline there:

*Aesthetics*
1. Essentialism
2. Art objects

*Epistemology*
1. Gettier problem
2. Infinite regression
3. Molyneux problem
4. Münchhausen trilemma
5. Qualia

*Ethics*
1. Moral luck

*Philosophy of language*
1. Moore's disbelief

*Philosophy of mathematics*
1. Mathematical objects

*Metaphysics*
1. Sorites paradox
2. Counterfactuals
3. Material implication

*Philosophy of mind*
1. Mind-body problem
2. Cognition and AI
3. Hard problem of consciousness

*Philosophy of science*
1. Problem of induction
2. Demarcation problem
3. Realism